# nanomsg pub/sub with multiple subscribers using binary msg and topic name

Tags: nanomsg

how we can send msg from publisher to subscriber on different topics in one structure    and how topics can be retrieved in subscriber.

- C/C++ code example

Comment: pub/sub  how to use nn_sendmsg and nn_recvmsg via using struct nn_msghdr

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** *"how we can send msg from publisher to subscriber on different topics in one structure...?"*

The **`pub`**-side can do just sending, like this :

```
#include <nanomsg/nn.h>
#include <nanomsg/pubsub.h>

...
int pub = nn_socket (AF_SP, NN_PUB);
assert (pub >= 0);
...

int nbytes;
char *addr = "inproc://example";

nn_bind(pub, addr);
...

nbytes = nn_send (pub, "a_Topic_#1abcdefghijklmnopqr", 28);
assert(nbytes == 28);

nbytes = nn_send (pub, "a_Topic_#2abcdefghijklmnopqr", 28);
assert(nbytes == 28);
...

nn_freemsg (buf);
...
```

> **Q :** *"...  and how topics can be retrieved in subscriber?"*

Using basically this mock-up principle, the **`sub`**-side has to subscribe first :

```
#include <nanomsg/nn.h>
#include <nanomsg/pubsub.h>

...
int sub = nn_socket (AF_SP, NN_SUB);
assert (sub >= 0);
...

int nbytes;
void *buf = NULL;
char *addr = "inproc://example";

nn_connect(sub, addr);
...

nn_setsockopt (sub, NN_SUB, NN_SUB_SUBSCRIBE, "a_Topic_#1", 10);
nn_setsockopt (sub, NN_SUB, NN_SUB_SUBSCRIBE, "a_Topic_#2", 10);
...

nbytes = nn_recv (sub, &buf, NN_MSG, 0);
assert (nbytes == 28);

nn_freemsg (buf);
...
```